# How to close window by clicking CANCEL button?

Tags: php, javascript, html

this php file will be opened as a pop-up window by clicking a button on other file. I included 2 buttons in this file, one for UPDATE and another for CANCEL. If user click on UPDATE data will be updated in databse.I want to close window automatically if user click on CANCEL button. But what's happening is if user clicks on CANCEL button, window is closing but data is getting updated in database. What should I do in-order to close the window without getting the data updated in database? 
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
    `<html>
     <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cms_style.css">    


 </head>

  <body>


  <?php

        $cid = $_GET['id'];
        $uid = $_GET['uid'];



    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("abcd",$con);


    if($uid==1) {

        updateRecord($cid);



    } else if (isset($_GET['id']) ) {


        $ResumeID = $_GET['id']; 
        $sql="SELECT * from data WHERE ResumeID=$ResumeID";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $Row=mysql_fetch_row($result); 


 ?> 
     <form align="center" action="update.php?id=<? echo "$Row[1]"?>&uid=1"
                          method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <input type="hidden" name="resumeid" value="<? echo "$Row[1]"?>">

    <? echo "<tr> <td> Resume ID </td><td>$Row[1]</td> </tr>" ?>                         

   <div align="center">
   <tr><td> Name of the Candidate</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="NameoftheCandidate" size="25" value="<? echo            
       "$Row[0]" ?>">   </td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>TelephoneNo</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="TelephoneNo" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[2]"?     
      >">            

        </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>       
    <td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" size="25" value="<? echo "$Row[3]"?>">
    </td>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitvalue" value="UPDATE" ></td>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL"         
     onClick="self.close()"></td>
    </tr>
    </div>                              
    </table>
    </form>

<?php
    } // end of else if



    function updateRecord($cid) {


          $sql="UPDATE data SET 
          NameoftheCandidate=\"$_POST[NameoftheCandidate]\",
         TelephoneNo='$_POST[TelephoneNo]',
          Email='$_POST[Email]' WHERE ResumeID=$_GET[id]";



        if(mysql_query($sql))
            echo "<p>Record updated Successfully</p>";
        else
            echo "<p>Record update failed</p>";


    } // end of update function


      ?>



     </body>
         </html>`
```

Comment: BTW, you should provide resulting static HTML code, not your source PHP+HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change type="submit" to "button"

```
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submitvalue" value="UPDATE" >
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="button" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL" onClick="self.close()"> 
</td>
```

Comment: @trendzcreator say your thanks by accepting my answer, by clicking green write symbol

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `return false;` after calling `self.close()`. Alternatively, you can replace `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">`.

Comment: Doing both is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['cancelvalue'])){
exit();
}

?>
```

Buttons client-side won't stop a script server side.

Something else, you can't use *isset* to check for the global arrays, if any values are passed the array will return true. You should use *empty* instead.